# Python - question about hashes and `None`

Tags: python

Why does `None` hash to `-1042159082` (which I found to be equal to number of bytes in a Gigabyte negated)?

I realize this doesn't really effect my code, but I'm curious.

Hashes are used for dictionary key look-ups, so I decided to experiment:

```
>>> D = {-1042159082: 'Hello', None: 'Hi'}
>>> D[None]
'Hi'
>>> D[-1042159082]
'Hello'
>>>
```

I understand this as Python seeing two identical hashes and then checking type to see what's what. Is that right?

```
>>> {False: 'Hello', 0: 'Hi'}
{False: 'Hi'}
>>> {0: 'Hi', False: 'Hello'}
{0: 'Hello'}
```

This is just weird. What's more is that the first key is kept and the second value is kept.

Is this sorcery, or could somebody help me understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About 2 values which may produce the same output when passed to the built-in `hash()` function (`None` and `-1042159082` in the question asked):

This is called a **collision** (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29) page on Wikipedia for more information about collisions).

The hashing algorithm which Python uses has a special way to figure out which value the person really wants when there is a collision (see [this](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c?revision=81029&view=markup) page in the source code of CPython (the main Python interpreter), starting at line 51, for information on collisions for dicts, at the time of writing this answer; [this](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/dictnotes.txt?view=markup) file also has notes on how dicts are implemented).

About what happens with `0` and `False` (and more useful info), see other answers to the current question.

Comment: That's all true but keep in mind that in the OP's example there isn't a hash collision: it's the *same* key value being given.  In Python, False is equal to the integer 0.

Comment: Ned Deily: Thanks, clarified what the part of the answer about collisions the answer is coming to answer.

Comment: @Ned - You're incorrect. `None` hashed to the same negative integer which was reused as another key, but both keys remained in the dictionary. This was inconsistent with the `False`: `0` example wherein the same action led to a different result. @Abafei, thanks for the correct answer. I looked into the source C code and it was quite interesting to see the conditionals pertaining to `Py_None`.

Comment: Yes, my answer was unclear and incomplete.  Abafei is correct that the first example (None) is definitely an example of a collision.  I misread your description and focused on the second part (False vs 0).  It's good to be looking at the C code.  CPython's implementation of dict objects has been fine tuned over the years and the hash table implementation is famous for its efficiency.

Answer (score 4):

You can not and should not depend on a particular hash value for a Python object.  It's implementation- and machine-dependent.  On my machine:

```
>>> hash(None)
268532216
```

As far as populating `dict` objects goes (there is no `hash` object in Python), perhaps the following will help:

```
>>> False == 0
True
>>> {0: 'Hello', 0: 'Hi'}
{0: 'Hi'}
>>> {0: 'Hi', 0: 'Hello'}
{0: 'Hello'}
>>> {False: 'Hello', False: 'Hi'}
{False: 'Hi'}
>>> {False: 'Hi', False: 'Hello'}
{False: 'Hello'}
```

When using the `dict` constructor, you are supplying two `key=value` pairs but both of them have the same key (i.e. hashable value) so, since key values in a dict must be unique, the last value is the one that is saved.  In other words, each of the constructors above is creating a one-item dict:

```
>>> print {False: 'Hello', 0: 'Hi'}
{False: 'Hi'}
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

No, even if two objects happen to have the same hash, they still won't cause a key collision. Python detects this and works around it (though please don't ask me how).

But `False` is the same as `0` and `True` is the same as `1`, so when you're using both in a dict construction, you're updating the value when adding another item with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

How do you figure None hashes to that value?

```
>>> d = {None:'hi'}
>>> d.get(-1042159082)
>>> d.get(None)
'hi'
>>>
>>> hash(None)
268532214
>>>
```

I wouldn't rely on the value of hashing None, ever.

As for the dictionary resolution using a literal, I'm assuming that internally, defining a key that 'equals' another, will just do an update instead of a straight add.

```
>>> class Key(object):
...     key = '1'
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return 1
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return hash(self) == hash(other)
... 
>>> class FakeKey(Key):
...     key = '2'
... 
>>> k = Key()
>>> >>> fk = FakeKey()
>>> d = {k:k,fk:fk}
>>> d
{<__main__.Key object at 0x100489f10>: <__main__.FakeKey object at 0x100489fd0>}
>>> ref = d[k]
>>> ref.key
'2'
>>> d.keys()[0].key
'1'
>>>
```

Appears I'm right (only appears).

Comment: I didn't figure, I just typed `hash(None)` into my interpreter. See Ned's answer to answer your questions about `hash`. Also, why wouldn't you rely on hashing `None`? It's an in-memory object, or do the Python docs say that somewhere?

Comment: What I meant was, I wouldn't rely on the value of hash(None) being consistent. Using None within a dict is fine, but using the value that hash(None) produces is not.

Comment: And there is seldom a reason to actually need to know the hash value of a Python object.  If you think you do, you're probably thinking about it the wrong way.  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hash